# Execute EXIT HANDLER for specific table

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure which manipulates two tables which also uses:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062 
BEGIN 
    ...
END;
```

My problem is that I want the EXIT HANDLER to catch duplicates for only one of the tables, is that possible?

Thank you,
Kate

Comment: I don't think you can: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html here it says you can only manager handlers for sql states

Comment: Sebas, thanks again :)  Based on the MySQL documentation I found that encapsulating the HANDLER solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is appropriate but I found a work around that works...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE some_procedure (IN some_id INT(11))
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO table1 ...

    SPROC:
    BEGIN

        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062 
        BEGIN 
            /* manage duplicate error for table2 */
        END;

        INSERT INTO table2 ...

    END;
END;
```